# SPRING BOOT access to entityManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to update a project made with spring and hibernate with springboot.

Everything seems ok, but I can't figure how to get the entityManager.

I'm not using spring data, so no domain nor repository is used.

In this project, services are annotated with @service and entityManager is autowire with: @PersistenceContext,

here an example of my service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6384460058124202695L;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    User user = entityManager.find(User.class, username);
    return user;
}
```

The problem here is that the entityManager is null. So I read in doc that if we want to manage the entityManager we have to configure it, so I did this in configuration file:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "services" });

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}
```

The application is launching, but still have the entityManager null.

Any clue?

Edit: adding my application class (Has it's a demo project, I put all the config in one file)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Value("${sec.cas.server}")
private String casServer;

@Value("${sec.app.server}")
private String appServer;

@Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
private String databaseDriverClassName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String databaseUsername;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String databasePassword;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}

@Bean
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() {
    ComboPooledDataSource datasource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        datasource.setDriverClass(databaseDriverClassName);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong driver class");
    }
    datasource.setJdbcUrl(databaseUrl);
    datasource.setUser(databaseUsername);
    datasource.setPassword(databasePassword);

    datasource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    datasource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(600);
    datasource.setMaxPoolSize(500);
    datasource.setMinPoolSize(50);
    datasource.setMaxStatements(0);

    datasource.setMaxConnectionAge(600);
    datasource.setMaxIdleTime(600);

    return datasource;
}


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    DefaultPersistenceUnitManager  unitManager = new DefaultPersistenceUnitManager ();
    unitManager.setDefaultDataSource(dataSource());
    unitManager.setPersistenceXmlLocations("classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"); //location of     your persistence.xml file
    unitManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "services" });
    unitManager.setDefaultPersistenceUnitName("entityManager");

   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
   em.setPersistenceUnitManager(unitManager);

   JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
   em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
   em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

   return em;
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect");
    return properties;
 }

    @Bean
    public JdbcDaoImpl jdbcUserService() {
        JdbcDaoImpl jdbcDaoImpl = new JdbcDaoImpl();
        jdbcDaoImpl.setEnableGroups(true);
        jdbcDaoImpl.setEnableAuthorities(true);
        jdbcDaoImpl.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return jdbcDaoImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService("http://"+appServer+"/j_spring_cas_security_check");
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
           casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(new UserServiceImpl());
        //casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(userServiceImpl.class);
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas20ServiceTicketValidator());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only");
        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper authenticationUserDetailsService() {
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper userDetailsByName = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper();
        userDetailsByName.setUserDetailsService(jdbcUserService());
        return userDetailsByName;
    }

    @Bean
    public Cas20ServiceTicketValidator cas20ServiceTicketValidator() {
        Cas20ServiceTicketValidator casServiceTicketValidator = new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator("https://"+casServer+"/cas");
        casServiceTicketValidator.setProxyCallbackUrl("http://"+appServer+"/");
        casServiceTicketValidator.setProxyGrantingTicketStorage(new ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl());
        return casServiceTicketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setProxyGrantingTicketStorage(new ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl());
        casAuthenticationFilter.setProxyReceptorUrl("/secure/receptor");
        return casAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl("https://"+casServer+"/cas/login");
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter());
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

Comment: It would be good to see what your main application class looks like since your are using Spring Boot

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of the `UserServiceImpl` is managed by spring? Generally if it is null it isn't managed by spring, spring would throw an exception if it cannot autowire a dependency.

Comment: I have put my application class in the main thread. UserServiceImpl is correctly managed I think. When application starts, I can put a breakpoint in the loadUserByUsername method and when app gets here,  I can see that entityManager is null at this point.

Comment: @partyboy: You posted your own solution to the problem. If you would click the checkmark to label the answer "accepted", it could be put to rest. (It currently gets bumped back to the main page on a regular basis, despite being answered...)

Answer (score 1):

Your `EntityManager` being `null` indicates that Spring isn't processing `@PersistenceContext` annotations in your `UserServiceImpl` instance.

You're creating an instance of `UserServiceImpl` manually as part of configuring your `CasAuthenticationProvider` bean. That means that Spring knows nothing about the instance and will not inject any of its dependencies. You need to use a Spring-created instance, for example by making it an argument of the `casAuthenticationProvider()` method.

Comment: thanks for you response Andy, 

So I have separate my config files : one for Websecurity and datasource, and in the main application class, add the persistenceBeanPostProcessor.

Unfortunatly I still have the problem. 

With the new added bean, do I still need to configure my own entityManager (override the spring boot auto config) ?

Comment: You should't need to configure the entity manager manually. Also, see my update. I've just noticed that you were creating an instance of UserServiceImpl manually.

Comment: Good point for the UserServiceImpl ! 
So, I try to inject my service with @Autowired in the configuration file, but doesn't seem to work ... So In the casAuthenticationProvider() method, I just get the bean this way:

    Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() { ...
    UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl =     (UserServiceImpl)this.context.getBean("userServiceImpl");

Now I get into the method loadUserByUsername with an entityManager not null !

Now a new problem occur : Entity are not binded, looking to resolve that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    DefaultPersistenceUnitManager unitManager = new DefaultPersistenceUnitManager();
    unitManager.setPersistenceXmlLocations("classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"); //location of your persistence.xml file.
    unitManager.setDefaultDataSource(dataSource);
```

In persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="entityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        //classes, etc...
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
em.setPersistenceUnitManager(unitManager);
em.setPersistenceUnitName("entityManager");
```

And then injet:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManager")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I'm starting implementing your solution. Got an error, cannot find a persistence unit in persistence.xml ... I think application can't find my persistence.xml in my classpath. I'll continue on monday to find out.

Comment: I try to config this way but I always get the error : o persistence unit with name 'entityManager' found

persistence.xml is in the classpath (look in the deployed app, file in classes/META-INF) everything looks ok

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Got it finally worked, no entityManager is needed to be redefined, just add the bean who get the @persistenceContext (before spring boot 1.2.0)

Here is my application context:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"services","model"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

Comment: @partyboy: This is your own solution to the problem. If you would click the checkmark to label this answer "accepted", it could be put to rest. (It currently gets bumped back to the main page on a regular basis, despite being answered...)

Comment: It's not legislation on the *name* Public Domain, but that German law simply disallows waiving your rights on something, so "I waive my rights / this is declared PD" is void by law, while "I am the author but license this as CC0" is ok... ;-\