# Obtaining handle to EntityManager in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any way to get a handle to the EntityManager for a given entity object? I'm using spring boot 1.2.3 with JPA starter and i'm further explicitly configuring multiple data sources with `@configuration`

I've checked [[resolved]SPRING BOOT access to entityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425067/resolvedspring-boot-access-to-entitymanager) and it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Thanks.

**EDIT: I added description of how my data sources are defined:**

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class DataSources {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="first.datasource")
    public DataSource getPrimaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="second.datasource")
    public DataSource getSecondDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="third.final.datasource")
    public DataSource getThirdFinalDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

In my application.yml I have the following sections

```
first.datasource:
  name: 'first_datasource',
  #other attributes...
second.datasource:
  name: 'second_datasource',
  #other attributes...
third.final.datasource:
  name: 'first_datasource',
  #other attributes...
```

So far I've tried both of @Stephane's suggestions but I get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

Let's say my entity is called `Customer` then I tried

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public FooService(@Qualifier("customerEntityManager") EntityManager entityManager) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But I also tried

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "customer") // also tried "customers" and "first_datasource"
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

with no luck.

Comment: It's a little tough to say without seeing how you've configured your JPA database.  Normally you should be able to use `@PersistenceContext` and you're good to go.  Could you show us how you've configured your database?

Comment: Thanks I got it. Only if you want a datasource other than primary you need to provide a unitName. Omitting the unit name lets you get the primary entity manager which finally worked for my purpose.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends how you've been configuring this but have you tried to *inject* the `EntityManager` with a qualifier that corresponds to the factory that created it?

Here is [a sample project with two data sources](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers). If you want to inject the `EntityManager` for order, just do the following in any Spring bean of the project

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public FooService(@Qualifier("orderEntityManager") EntityManager entityManager) {
        ...
    }

}
```

For customer, use the `customerEntityManager`.

Of course you can use the persistent unit name instead, that is

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "customers")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "orders")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Check the configuration of the project for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane. In the case of Spring-Boot where I am not defining the persistence.xml, where how I find the name of the persistence unit? I tried multiple guesses but I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Comment: I am confused. Spring Boot does not support auto-config for multiple entity managers, you have to configure that yourself. If you have multiple datasources and one that is `@Primary`, then what is your question exactly? Boot will create only on entity manager and so adding `@PersistenceContext` (or `@Autowired`) is all that's needed.

Comment: I am sure there is something I'm missing. Anyway I added some more detail to the question about how I create my data sources. I don't know if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Like I told you already, *Spring Boot does not support auto-config for multiple entity managers, you have to configure that yourself.* So your project has 3 data sources and *ONE* entity manager (on the primary datasource). If you inject the entity manager (no qualifier, plain `@PersistenceContext` you'll get the only one that exists. It's a bit weird you didn't start by that). If you want 3 entity managers, please follow the link to the sample project I've provided.

Comment: Hi, Stéphane. Thanks for your sample, itis very good job! But I have a question, why do Entity and Rspository class have to be in the same package? how can I do if I want to split them to different package?

Comment: Who said they should? Look at the configuration referring to the package of `Customer.class` for the customer DataSource. Just put whatever package you want there. You need to make sure to have separate packages for `Order` and `Customer` though.