# Can Spring Boot JPA and JDBC share same DataSource/connections?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource

Spring Boot here. I currently use JPA/Hibernate along with `CrudRepository` interfaces for all my JPA entities and its been working great for me so far. I have a need to execute a complex query that requires a `UNION` and from what I can tell, Hibernate doesn't support unions (or at least does not support them easily). I've verified by trying about a *dozen* different JPQL queries in my `CrudRepository` and all of them fail because Hibernate (the JPA provider) doesn't like the `UNION`.

So, I'm totally fine with just using a raw JDBC query in this one case and doing my own quasi-OR Mapping from the resultant `ResultSet` back into instances of my entities.

What I'm concerned about has to do with managing the JDBC connections. I configure my JPA/Hibernate connection configurations in the application config (YAML) file:

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: none
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp_db?useSSL=false
    username: root
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
```

- Will I need two `DataSource`s, one for JPA/Hibernate and another for my JDBC (both are connecting to the exact same DB after all)
- Will I have performance or network/socket issues by maintaining these two `DataSource` instances?
  Anything special I need to do
- Currently I don't *believe* my JPA/Hibernate configs make use of connection pooling, but ideally I'd like to use [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for the pooling for both JPA/Hibernate as well as my raw JDBC queries
- Is there a way to make both my `CrudRepository` instances (JPA/Hibernate) and my raw JDBC connections use the same exact `DataSource`/config? If so what would this config/code look like?

I know there's several questions in here, but I believe that the right battle-weary JDBC/JPA veteran will be able to address all of them with a quick snippet of config and/or code! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can execute SQL queries with JPA as well. EntityManager.createNativeQuery. No need to use JDBC.

Comment: Right, thanks @Simon....but going through JPA will elicit Hibernate as the provider, and Hibernate doesn't like my UNIONs.

Comment: NO! Hibernate will execute the SQL statement as it is.

Comment: Ahhh, interesting. Thanks @SimonMartinelli (+1 for all 3). Quick question though: I perused [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/) which makes it seem like I just need to have access to an `entityManager` instance. However I've been abstracted away from all of that up until now, using `CrudRepositories`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32027079/4009451) it *sounds* like I can just use `@Autowired` to inject a `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "mytable")` into my code? What would this look like in practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hibernate/SQL**

First read the docs how to execute SQL with Hibernate:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql

Example:

```
List<Object[]> persons = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Person" ).getResultList();
```

**HikariCP**

If you can use Spring Boot 2 because then HikariCP is the default connection pool.

Otherwise read this article:

http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/07/26/use-hikaricp-next-spring-boot-project

Comment: Thanks @Simon (+1) - this is awesome! Quick question though, how do I get access to the correct `entityManager` managing my desired table/entities? Thanks again!

Comment: Please find more info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data

Comment: And you can inject the EntityManager in your class